# Does my Application use Log4j?

Tags: log4j

I have 20 application deployed to a single weblogic server [JVM]. I have been given a task to find out which of them uses log4j and which does not use log4j.

What is the best and quickest way of finding this out ?

Note: All I have is application "EARS" and "WARS" with no access to source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a linux box grep will actually search class files for regex matches - so you could do something like:

```
find [deployment_directory] -iname '*.ear' -o -iname '*.war' | xargs grep -R org.apache.log4j
```

I'm sure it's not the most elegant solution, but it would give you every deployment that has a dependency with the Apache log4j namespace.

Comment: I have HP-UX can you help me with the command for the same ?

Comment: sorry, can't help you there, don't know much about HP-UX.  However, the concept would remain the same: get all .ears and .wars (be sure to avoid case sensitivity), then search those individually for the dependency.  There's probably a better way to do this though...